# Assigning routes to items in an array using React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am new to JavaScript, React and Router. While I am familiar with basic routing the below example is a bit more complex. I haven't been able to find any examples on Stack that are this specific and I am stuck.

I am bascially trying to assign routes to items in an array that can be accessed within a  element where they are rendered. So when said items are clicked on, they route to the desired path. I know I can do this if I broke up the array, but doing so would mess up the styling of {classes.taskList} (not shown). Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { List } from '@material-ui/core/list';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import NavLink from 'react-router-dom/NavLink';
import Link from 'react-router-dom/Link';

const formList = [
    { label: 'Form 1'},
    { label: 'Form 2'},
    { label: 'Form 3'}];

{/* This is an example route. I want to assign the route the first item in formList
  <NavLink style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} to = "/Form 1" exact activeStyle ={ { color:'green'}}> Form 1 </NavLink>,
  <Route path = "/Form 1" exact render = {()=>{
    return ( <Form 1/>);
    }
}/>
*/}

const renderRow = ({ getItemProps, item }) => (
    <div {...getItemProps({ item })}>
        {item.label} <span>{item.count}</span>
    </div>
);

const mySidebar = ({ classes }) => (

    <List
     source={formList}
     rowRenderer={renderRow}
     className={classes.taskList}
    />

);

export default withStyles(styles)(mySidebar);
```

Comment: Where is renderRow coming from?

Comment: I added renderRow, please see edit

Comment: Could you add a `<Link >` somewhere in your renderRow?